# emacs --daemon is not loading gui elements

Tags: emacsclient, daemon, emacs-daemon, speedbar, scroll-bars

I defined emacsclient as default editor in `.bashrc` so emacs -daemon will be called upon startup:

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
export EDITOR=emacsclient
```

But compared to a normal load without client, if I call `emacsclient afile`, then some ui elements are missing, like the scrollbar, which will disappear, and the speedbar pictures, which will be replaced with "+" sign. Apparently the init file is not fully loaded by emacs daemon? What could possibly caused the difference and how can it be fixed?

[image]

**a)** Above is a normal load with **emacs afile**, same with **emacs ; emacsclient -c afile**.

**b)** Below is a client load with **emacsclient -c afile** after **emacs --daemon &**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you have code running at init time which checks to see whether or not you are running a GUI emacs (via `display-graphic-p` or similar), and configures certain settings based on that.

`(display-graphic-p)` returns `t` at init time when a GUI non-daemon Emacs starts, because a graphical frame is created beforehand; but that function call returns `nil` at init time when a daemon starts, as no GUI frame is current at that time (and obviously the daemon has no idea whether any GUI frames are ever *going* to exist).