# Emacs daemon does not load my init.el completely but plain emacs does

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon, gui-emacs

When I run `emacs`, everything is ok, my `init.el` is read. However, after starting a daemon (`emacs --daemon`), an emacsclient GUI frame (`emacsclient -c`) is not configured for the following setting:

- font size

```el
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Inconsolata-12.5")
```

- icons in the mode line (*doom mode line*)

```el
(use-package doom-modeline
  :init (doom-modeline-mode 1))
```

- ivy package (until I use it)

```el
(use-package ivy
  :diminish
  :bind (("C-s" . swiper)
     :map ivy-minibuffer-map
     ("TAB" . ivy-alt-done)
     ("C-l" . ivy-alt-done)
     ("C-j" . ivy-next-line)
     ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
     :map ivy-switch-buffer-map
     ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
     ("C-l" . ivy-done)
     ("C-d" . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)
     :map ivy-reverse-i-search-map
     ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
     ("C-d" . ivy-reverse-i-search-kill))
  :config
  (ivy-mode 1))
```

---

[Here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30160/emacs-daemon-is-not-loading-gui-elements) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/opening-frames-from-emacs-daemon?rq=1),  it is mentioned that Emacs daemon doesn't know about the graphical frame, so every/some option that is needed for GUI is sort of neglected. In my `init.el` I commented out every line that has that option, but it didn't help.

I couldn't find anything helpful in the `Emacs` or `Emacsclient` manuals.
Are there any arguments that I should add when starting Emacs daemon (other than `--daemon`) or emacsclient (other than `-c`)? or do I have to edit init.el file?

Debian Buster/Sid -- Emacs version: 27.1

Comment: Have you tried calling `set-face-attribute` from `after-make-frame-functions`? The Emacs daemon reads your `user-init-file` with a dummy initial frame that is never shown, so settings against that frame don't usually affect normal frames created thereafter with `emacsclient -t` or `emacsclient -c`.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do that call. could you give me hint?

Comment: `(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions (lambda (f) (set-face-attribute 'default f :font "Inconsolata-12.5")))`

Comment: BTW, see [`(info "(emacs) Fonts")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html) for preferred ways of changing the font.

Comment: It works. Thanks Basil!!